# Why Swashbuckle.aspnet.core.swagger not being recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I've installed though `nuget package manager` the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger` and had included the using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger` on the top, but I get error on the `Info{ Title}` methods. 
Can anyone please suggest how to solve this issue.

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My DAB API", Version = "V3.2.2" });
            });
```

Answer (score 19):

I find Solution.

For version 5

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;


services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

Comment: If need Contact inside of OpenApiInfo then it too needs to be OpenApiContact -> new OpenApiContact { Contact = new OpenApiContact { Name = "", Email = "" }}

Answer (score 7):

If you are using DotnetCore (>= 3.0) Make sure you are using Pre-Release (as of now Dec-19) of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package which is `-Version 5.0.0-rc4`. I mistakenly installed the latest stable version `4.0.1` in which `Microsoft.OpenApi.Models` was missing.

[See More On Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in ASP.NET Core 2.1 web api but I have resolved issue by first installing the lower version of package & upgrading it version by version

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.1.0 and then after I have upgraded the package version by version  until I got the same error but I haven't received same error again even upgrading till swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc2 & its now working properly with following configuration

Use namespace as following because Info class is not more used in latest version of swagger instead of OpenApiInfo class used to describe about swagger metadata

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
```

then use the following code in Startup.cs class under the ConfigureServices method

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "www.compilemode.com", Version = "v1" });
        });
```

This is very strange resolution but this is the only work around I have found after spending lots of time.

Comment: This comes from version 5.0.0 and above (not by upgrading it version by version). More info here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58975118/244916

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger` and try this package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution, Finally. I installed Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 4.0.1. Obviously it wasn't working with the latest version which is 5.

Answer (score -1):

Just install package Microsoft.OpenApi to resolve the issue

Answer (score -1):

while upgrading project to .net core 5.0 or 6.0, SwaggerDoc does have the SwaggerDoc("v1", info), instead of use SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo());