# cannot convert from 'Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo' to 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info'

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle, openapi

I'm getting this error when tryign to run swashbuckle. Any ideas?

I have this in my ConfigureServices Class

```
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "testing", 
                Version = "v1" });
            });
```

And this in my Configure Class

```
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this same issue today. After looking at the Microsoft documentation, it appears that `SwaggerDoc` is looking for a string and an `Info` parameter. At the top of your file make sure that you include `using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;` and replace `OpenApiInfo` with `Info`.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "testing", 
            Version = "v1" });
        });
```

Comment: I was coming from here [Microsoft swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), and don't understand why they reference OpenApiInfo

Comment: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger 5.5.1 does not have a type Info, only OpenApiInfo

Answer (score 10):

Before **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 5.0.0** (which is not yet released, on november 2019), SwaggerDoc extension method requires a `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info` parameter. So, you have to write :

```
// Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

Especially, if you are coming from : [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware)

Beginning with version 5.0.0, SwaggerDoc extension method now requires a `Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo` parameter.

Comment: Any idea when we can expect the final version on this? I've checked [the pace of versions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/5.0.0-rc4) but wasn't exactly any wise after that. Is the current state of the candidate version very shaky or am I safe to go with it and expect it released in a few months? Where can one stuff like that? Suggestions?

Comment: No idea about the final version. A release candidate version is _usually_ enough stable to be used. I use it on my project for a client and I expect it to be released soon.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample for swagger 5.5.0 &> for C#

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "API Title is",
                    Version = "v1"
                });
            });
        }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        //app.UseMvc();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 api test");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to Upgrading the package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` to the latest version `v 5.0.0-rc5` solved the problem.

in that package its already including `Microsoft.OpenApi` package assembly you don't need to addon additionally.
you `OpenApiInfo`, `OpenApiContract`, and much more property are directly inherited with the upgradable package.